# Низкая скорость в туннеле IPsec между Freebsd в одну сторону

Tags: сеть, freebsd

Есть 2 территориально распределенных офиса соединенных туннелем. 
Оба офиса имеют интернет канал 100мегабит статический IP. Шлюзы на FreeBSD. Схема такая:

```
192.168.1.0/24----FREEBSD_GW1--ipsec-tunnel--FREEBSD_GW0----192.168.0.0/24
```

Когда передаю данные, независимо от протокола, из GW0 в GW1 то скорость нормальная близка к 100мегабитам. В обратную же сторону скорость передачи колеблется около 200кбайт.сек.(тоесть около 2мегабит).

Причем, если обращаюсь на внешний IP GW и делаю передачу не через туннель в ту же сторону, используя например FTP то скорость нормальная.

Скорость upload/download в интернет нормальная в обоих офисах. 
Ошибок в логах racoon и на шлюзах нет. 
До какого-то момента все работало нормально. В один момент увеличился пинг до удаленного офиса с 2мс до 47мс после этого начались проблемы. Обращался к провайдеру - ни чем не могут помочь.

Подскажите как определить где затыкается трафик, почему только в одну сторону? Какие инструменты можно использовать на freebsd?  Rонфиг ракуна одинаков на оба сервера:

```
padding {
    maximum_length 20 ;
    randomize off ;
    strict_check off ;
    exclusive_tail off ;
}

listen {
    isakmp <внешний ip> [500] ;
}

timer {
    counter 5 ;
    interval 20 sec ;
    persend 1 ;
    phase1 30 sec ;
    phase2 15 sec ;
}

remote  anonymous {
    exchange_mode main,aggressive ;
    doi ipsec_doi ;
    situation identity_only ;
    nonce_size 16 ;
    initial_contact on ;
    proposal_check obey ;

    proposal {
        encryption_algorithm 3des ;
        hash_algorithm md5 ;
        authentication_method pre_shared_key ;
        dh_group 2 ;
    }
}

sainfo anonymous {
    pfs_group 2 ;
    lifetime time 5 min ;
    encryption_algorithm 3des ;
    authentication_algorithm hmac_md5 ;
    compression_algorithm deflate ;
}
```

Comment: а покажите `ifconfig` шлюзов, вдруг что

Comment: Посмотрите tcpdump'ом на трафик в проблемную сторону.